# Explode doesn't remove comma from value in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have value in database field which has `,` after the name like this `file.pdf,`. I'm tried to remove it with explode but I got error `FPDF error: Unable to find pointer to xref table` when I try to read and generate pdf from this row in database... If I remove manually comma from phpmyadmin everything work perfectly. This is the fragment of the source where I try to explode...

```
    foreach($files as $file) {

    $sql = "SELECT file FROM documents WHERE id = :id"; 
    $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(":id", $file);
    $result->execute();                 

    $resArray = $result->fetchAll();

    foreach ( $resArray as $res )
    {
         $items = explode(',', $res["file"]);

         foreach ($items as $item) {

           $pdf->addPDF($fileFolder.$item);             
         }  
        }           
}
```

Comment: What type of data is given from the `$res` array? Also didn't know it was possible to run a `foreach` function inside of each other :P (`do a print_r on the $res array`)

Comment: res array hold pdf documents. `print_r($res) -> 89b135b595e9224ceacaa470a1e5d5aa.pdf,`

Comment: I'm lazy so I'd just use `str_replace(',', $res['file'], '');` :') - Removes all of them just incase ;)

Comment: Not a good idea, because this would also remove commas in different places (not only trailing ones), e.g. `To be or not to be, this is the question.pdf` would errornously be changed to `To be or not to be this is the question.pdf` without the comma.

Comment: Took it as a challenge to not use `rtrim` and come up with something but YOU WIN THIS ROUND!

Comment: This is not the place for challenges like this which are only confusing for the OP or other readers. (Plus, the OP needs `.pdf` and not `.php` and who knows, maybe there are other extensions as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't remove a comma, instead it splits the string into multiple parts using the comma as separator. So you effectively get two strings: One with `file.pdf` and an empty one (because the part after the comma is nothing), and you are iterating over both using `foreach`, so you are calling `addPDF` twice, one time with an empty string (which is probably what causes the error).

What you need is this:

```
foreach ( $resArray as $res )
{
     $pdf->addPDF($fileFolder . rtrim($res["file"], ","));
}
```

[`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rtrim.php) is used here to explicitely remove trailing characters (here the comma).

Answer (score 3):

This will delete every last ','.

```
$item = rtrim($res["file"], ",");
$pdf->addPDF($fileFolder.$item);
```

Documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php

instead of:

```
$items = explode(',', $res["file"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

use rtrim($res["file"], ",") to delete last comma